# Translating a couple of sentences

Tags: translation

I'm currently studing from Genki-1 and I would like to know if I understand these sentences correctly, thank you :)

あなたの町に日本のレストランがありますか。- Do you have a Japanese restaurant in your town?

あなたの学校に何がありますか - what do you have in your school?

この教室にだれがいますか - Who is in that classroom ?

あなたの国に何がありますか - What is in your country?

日曜日に何がありますか　- What happens at Sunday?

Comment: Your understanding seems ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good but i'd make this one change.

この教室にだれがいますか - Who is in ***this*** classroom ?